# Copying multiple files in a different location Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of files with the audio signals in them and I am trying to copy-paste them in another direction ( another folder). I have around 20 folders which include 10 audio signals in each folder. I would like to copy and paste them one by one with the same names and also be able to apply some filtering in the audio signals as per the below code before I will transfer the audio signals to the new folder. However, I do not want to use the dir function. Can anyone advise what other options do I have?
Many thanks in advance.

my code for the filtering it will be something like this.

```
imp = [0.2,0.4,0.5,-3];
nImp = length(imp);

inpSignal=[zeros(nImp,1);inpSignal;zeros(nImp,1)];
nSamplesNew = length(inpSignal);
outSignal= zeros(nSamplesNew,1);
for i=1+nImp:nSamples+nImp,
    outSignal(i)=imp(1)*inpSignal(i)+imp(2)*inpSignal(i-1);
end
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `dir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls` instead of `dir`. This returns a `char` array instead of a structure. The overall approach remains the same. I recommend using a file extension as a filter to exclude directories. You may need to iterate through a few times if you're copying more than one type of file.

```matlab
srcDirectory = 'C:\Temp';
fileFilter = '*.wav';
destDirectory = 'D:\Temp';

files = ls(fullfile(srcDirectory,fileFilter));
for fileIdx = 1:size(files,1)
    filename = strtrim(string(files(fileIdx,:)));
    srcPath = fullfile(srcDirectory,filename);
    destPath = fullfile(destDirectory,filename);
    copyfile(srcPath,destPath);
end
```

### EDIT

If `outSignal` is the signal you want to save off to a new file, you can write the save statement right in line after processing (i.e. filtering).

```matlab
imp = [0.2,0.4,0.5,-3];
nImp = length(imp);
newDirectory = 'C:\Temp\Some Folder';

inpSignal=[zeros(nImp,1);inpSignal;zeros(nImp,1)];
nSamplesNew = length(inpSignal);
outSignal= zeros(nSamplesNew,1);
for i=1+nImp:nSamples+nImp,
    outSignal(i)=imp(1)*inpSignal(i)+imp(2)*inpSignal(i-1);
end
newFilePath = fullfile(newDirectory,filename);
audiowrite(newFilePath,outsignal,Fs)
```

I'm assuming you have `filename` from when you opened the original file for processing. Use `help audiowrite` for additional info on this function.

If you need to append a unique number for multiple signal files originating from the same `filename`, you can use something like this:

```matlab
[~, filename, ext] = fileparts(filename);
newFilePath = fullfile(newDirectory,[filename,'_',num2str(sigIdx,'%03.0f'),ext]);
```

Where `sigIdx` is your loop control variable for looping through the signals.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, if I will play around with your code I think I can manage to make it work.

Comment: @BoilermarkerRV in my case it was but I have a small issue, I have 1 folder which contains 20 files(20different names) and within the file, it has around 10 audio signals how can I read all the files? as at the moment I am able to copy the data from one file and not from every file. Finally, I would like to copy also and the names of the files, so in practice, it should copy all files and have the same names but only the signals should change as they are going to be filtered first.

Comment: @Grey_Hunter, If each file contains 10 audio files, are you saying you want there to be 200 files (20 files x 10 signals/file) in the new directory? What is the file format? Can you share the code you're using to do the filtering? Seems like you just need to add a line in the current script to save the new signal once the processing is complete.

Comment: @BoilermarkerRV yes you are correct, I have not completed the filtering yet but it should be something like this:                                                                  "imp = [0.2,0.4,0.5,0.5,-3];
nImp = length(imp);

inpSignal=[zeros(nImp,1);inpSignal;zeros(nImp,1)];
nSamplesNew = length(inpSignal);


outSignal= zeros(nSamplesNew,1);

for i=1+nImp:nSamples+nImp,
    outSignal(i)=imp(1)*inpSignal(i)+imp(2)*inpSignal(i-1);
end "  by the way how can I add 'single marks 'like this' in a signal for example from this signal.wav to this 'signal.wav'and store it in a string?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have tried so far. This will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: in the case that I would like to copy only the folders and not the wav signals what ending this line of code should have? fileFilter = '*.wav'; if I will leave it blank it copies everything.

Comment: In order to distinguish files from folders, you will need to either 1) use the `dir` function wich returns the `isdir` field or 2) parse the full path of a specific file in the folder you want to copy. You may find the functions [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html?s_tid=srchtitle) and [`filesep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html?s_tid=srchtitle) helpful.

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

### Using MATLAB

If your signals are within/generated by the MATLAB file you can do this. Otherwise, if your audio files are just residing in another directory the other answer posted works like a charm.

```
%Test audio signals%
[Audio_1,Fs_1] = audioread("Audio_1.m4a");
[Audio_2,Fs_2] = audioread("Audio_2.m4a");
[Audio_3,Fs_3] = audioread("Audio_3.m4a");
[Audio_4,Fs_4] = audioread("Audio_4.m4a");
[Audio_5,Fs_5] = audioread("Audio_5.m4a");

%Directory you want to save in%
Directory = "/Users/michael/Documents/MATLAB/Tutorials/Save_Signals_Folder/";
addpath(Directory);  

%Writing audio to new directory%
audiowrite(Directory + 'Audio_1_New.m4a',Audio_1,Fs_1);
audiowrite(Directory + 'Audio_2_New.m4a',Audio_2,Fs_2);
audiowrite(Directory + 'Audio_3_New.m4a',Audio_3,Fs_3);
audiowrite(Directory + 'Audio_4_New.m4a',Audio_4,Fs_4);
audiowrite(Directory + 'Audio_5_New.m4a',Audio_5,Fs_5);
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I forgot to mention the signals could be up to 1000. Is there an easier way for that?

Comment: @Grey_Hunter Using a loop would be a much more concise way. Are the signals from a MATLAB file?

Comment: Do you mean if they are store in the Matlab location? if yes. No, they are not.

Comment: So they're just files in a folder/directory.